# How to generate a random sequence of binary strings of fixed size ( say 36 bits ) in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to generate a unique random sequence of 50 Binary strings of size 36 bits each. I tried doing nextInt followed by toBinaryString which didn't solve my problem as nextInt don't support such big numbers and also checked nextString which generates string of some random characters (not 0/1) is there any other way to achieve this ? 
And to add one more requirement I want 36 bits to be present at every time suppose if some random generator generated 3 as a number I want the output as 000...(34)11.

I'm quite new to scala, Pardon me if my question seemed irrelavant or redundant.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary string of size 36 bits"? Is it string or number or byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
val r = scala.util.Random
val a: immutable.Seq[Int] = (0 to 50).map(_ => r.nextInt(1000000))
val y = a.map( x => {
   val bin = x.toBinaryString
   val zero = 36 - bin.length
   List.fill(zero)(0).mkString("") ++ bin
})
println(Random.shuffle(y))
```